# How to make rsync display only files being copied, not all the folders which are scanned?

Tags: rsync

My weekly backup script contains a bunch of bash statements like these:

```
rsync -va /source_path/ /destination_path/
```

Now, this works great but the -v (verbose) option doesn't behave exactly like I want. What I want is that it should display only the changed files which are being copied, and not each and every folder it scans.

For example, if `document1` and `document2` folders are unchanged, but a file is changed in `document3`, then the display will be as follows:

```
document1/
document2/
document3/
document3/foo.txt
```

If I omit the `-v` option altogether, its totally silent and doesn't display anything at all. I want the output display but I'm only interested in the last line (foo.txt) which is the file being copied, not the dozens of folders which `rsync` scans such as document1, document2, etc.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: That's already how rsync works.  It's listing those directories because it thinks they're not in sync.  Please run with the `-i` flag and include the output in your question.

Comment: The directories might be getting sync'd just to update their timestamp. Use -i to see exactly why they being synced. You might try -c (checksum) or --size-only, or just filter them out with | egrep -v '/$'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your description is already how `rsync` works.  The only files it displays with -v are ones that it is either transferring or changing.  So each time it runs, it sees there is some difference with the directories.

A common reason for this is that the source and destination are on different filesystems and the ownership or permissions can't be copied exactly, and each invocation is trying to do so.

To confirm this, run the `rsync` with `-i` (or `--itemize-changes`).  This will display a code that shows the reason `rsync` has decided the file needs work.  If its an ownership or something (and you decide you don't need this information), you can turn off the syncing of it with `--no-owner` or similar.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks @BowlOfRed. My source hard drive was using the EXT4 file system, and destination hard drive was using NFTS, so I kept getting those pointless directory listings described in the question above even though no files within those directories were being modified. Simply reformatting my destination drive to use EXT4 solved the problem.

Comment: It would be better to use `--omit-dir-times` (`-O`), if it's the timestamps on the directories that are the issue.  That way you don't really affect the way non-directories are synchronized.